# Почему вылетает приложение после нажатия на кнопку?

Tags: java, android

После нажатия на кнопку программа должна  задать значение "discrTV" (id TextView) значением из "aET" (id EditText), но она крашится. Вот код из mainactivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView discrTV = findViewById(R.id.discr);
        EditText aET = findViewById(R.id.aET);
        Button btngo = findViewById(R.id.btngo);

    btngo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            String txt = aET.getText().toString();
            a = Integer.parseInt(txt);
            discrTV.setText(a);
       }
```

Comment: Крашится с какой ошибкой?

Comment: Я не знаю. Просто написано "Приложение постоянно останавливается".

Comment: Где написано? Андроид студия так не пишет.

Comment: Проблема еще в том что у меня нет Android Studio или Eclipse.

Comment: Если нет, надо установить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод setText() принимает строку, ты передаешь целое число:

```
a = Integer.parseInt(txt);
discrTV.setText(a);
```

Приложение ищет строку с идентификатором, равным этому числу, не находит и крашится. Нужно передавать текст:

```
String txt = aET.getText().toString();
discrTV.setText(txt);
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, все получилось!

Comment: Я подправил. Нет смысла парсить строку, то, что уже и есть строка.